# UWP ListView: How to expand an item when select it?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a listview containing some item. And I want to expand the item to show detail information when I select one item, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: There is no Default Control that does this. However there are CustomControls for similar Behaviour. Take a look at [this](http://deanchalk.com/a-xaml-uwp-custom-control-the-expander/)

Comment: @AVKNaidu, It's very kind of you to provide such a CustomControl, but I want to say with the default `ListView` control, this work can be done, you can check my answer for details.

Comment: @AVKNaidu your solution is amazing but I prefer raw ListView control. Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't check the `CustomControl` carefully which provided by @AVK Naidu, which is good and seems can solve your problem. But I need to say here, it is totally possible to do this work with the default `ListView` control, what you need is just changing the `DataTemplate` for your `ListViewItem` when it is selected.

Just for example here:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="Normal" x:Key="Normal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="Detail" x:Key="Detail">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="Details:" FontSize="30" Foreground="Blue" Margin="0,10" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Normal}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Collection}" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind for `listView_SelectionChanged`:

```cs
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Assign DataTemplate for selected items
    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
        lvi.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Detail"];
    }
    //Remove DataTemplate for unselected items
    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
        lvi.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Normal"];
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is absolute what I want! Thank you^_^

Comment: But I feel it's not property to assign different size to different item, cuz this will influence user experience in some way. So finally I add a detail page for my app.

Comment: @THaGKI9, `But I feel it's not property to assign different size to different item`, you mean not properly? I think it bases on what you need to achieve in your app. And implementation a master/detail is also a method, to implement this, you can refer to the official [Master/detail sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail).